# Forwad class declaration for class members

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I'm facing problems because I want my includes to keep out of header files and stick them in sources to reduce inclusion of headers.

although the following classes are using goocanvas libraries the problem is of plain c++ rules...

the following class is the class that uses another class (which is forward declared)

```
#include <goocanvasmm/canvas.h> // due to: table main widget
namespace roulette
{
    class surface; // forward declared classes
    class mesh;

    class table final : public Goocanvas::Canvas
    {
    public:
        table ();
    private:
        Glib::RefPtr<surface> m_surface;  // using forward declared classes
        Glib::RefPtr<mesh> m_mesh;
    };
}
```

now here is the entry point for the above 'table' class

```
#include "surface.hpp"  // here we include forward declared classes
#include "mesh.hpp" // same here
#include "table.hpp"    // and the header it self

namespace roulette
{
    table::table() :  // ERROR: ALLOCATION OF INCOMPLETE TYPE
        m_surface(Glib::RefPtr<surface>(new surface)),  
        m_mesh(Glib::RefPtr<mesh>(new mesh(9, 29, 0, 0, 26, 19)))
    {
             /* implementation */
    }
}
```

how ever when including the headers 'mesh' and 'surface' in the header instead of source file everything is fine.
how to solve this so I don't have to include headers in header file?

edit:
here are header of 'mesh' and 'surface'

```
#include <goocanvasmm/table.h> // due to: inheritance

namespace roulette
{
    class mesh final : public Goocanvas::Table
    {
    public:
        mesh (short rows, short columns,
                double x = 0.0,
            double y = 0.0,
            double width = 0.0,
            double height = 0.0);
};
```

}

```
#include <string>   // due to: image path placeholder
#include <gdkmm/pixbuf.h>   // due to: image loading
#include <goocanvasmm/itemsimple.h> // due to: ItemSimple class inheritance

class surface final : public Goocanvas::ItemSimple
{
public:
    surface ();

    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> get_chip(short value);

private:
    // members
    std::string m_data_path;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> m_image;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> m_chip1, m_chip5, m_chip25, m_chip50, m_chip100;

    // methods
    void simple_paint_vfunc(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr, const Goocanvas::Bounds& bounds) override;
};
```

Comment: _"I want my includes to keep out of header files"_  Why is that?  Did you read something to suggest that was a good practice?

Comment: Can you elaborate further on precisely what code is causing what error message(s) from your compiler? You should only need to include `mesh` and `surface` in the source file.

Comment: Show (maybe shortened) surface.hpp and mesh.hpp.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this may be the issue that you have a default destructor. The default destructor will be defined in the header file, and (I assume) that Glib::RefPtr<T> needs T to be defined to do that.

Comment: @Mark B yes that's exactly the problem, I can't include them in source file because of error ( use of incomplete type) I have to include them in heder file (table.hpp) in order to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Glib::RefPtr`, like many other smart pointers, needs a full type, not only forward declaration. So I am afraid you need to include the headers in the `table` header. Or you can utilise Pimpl idiom - see e.g. http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/ .

Comment: I'll stick with your suggestion, pimpl idiom seems to bring additional overhead so I'll not use it.. thanks